# Implementing jQuery AJAX with jsonp response

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am having problem implementing **jQuery AJAX with jsonp** response. I try to access it but my failed callback function is called. I want my success callback function to get called.

Also note that on plain JavaScript i have already implemented it and i know about jsonp and cross domain ajax fundas. It on jQuery where I am failing.

The jsonp location is - **[here](https://www.demo.yogihosting.com/jquery/jquery-jsonp/data1.json)**

The code is:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.demo.yogihosting.com/jquery/jsonp/data1.json",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(result, status, xhr) {
    alert(result);
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
  }
});
```

You can view this on [jQuery AJAX with jsonp on CodePen](https://codepen.io/YogiHosting/pen/YraZpv).

Please help !

Comment: Can you post your failed callback error message?

Comment: @SamDev i am trying to fetch jsonp response from localhost and i am getting this error - ' jQuery31006235097177340809_1507490891841 was not called 200 load'

Comment: try with dataType: "json"

Comment: its still not working.

Comment: Similar like your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363853/ajax-with-jquery-200-ok-but-not-success and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363853/ajax-with-jquery-200-ok-but-not-success

Comment: @SamDev not sure why you'd think that would work, given that JSON and JSONP are not intercompatible in the slightest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSONP format you're calling has a callback of `processJSONPResponse`, so you need to set that in the `jsonpCallback` parameter of your AJAX request:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#jsonpButton1").click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.demo.yogihosting.com/jquery/jsonp/data1.json",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      type: "POST",
      jsonpCallback: 'processJSONPResponse', // add this property
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(result, status, xhr) {
        console.log(result);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="jsonpButton1">Button 1</button>
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qeov0Lnv/)

Note that I had to place the working example in a fiddle as SO does not allow insecure outbound requests to be made.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly - jsonpCallback: 'processJSONPResponse' was the thing missing from my code.